# Buffering in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers, buffer

I have some line layers ,I wan't to create 0.5km and 1km buffer around the lines.

How to create the the buffer in OpenLayers 3 and which layer use like wms,wps or wfs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [JSTS](http://bjornharrtell.github.io/jsts/) library to do the buffer, which can then be converted to OpenLayers. This is demonstrated in the [buffer example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/jsts.html) among those featured by OpenLayers.

Here's a snippet:

```
// feature is an instance of ol.Feature
var feature;

// convert the OpenLayers geometry to a JSTS geometry
var jstsGeom = parser.read(feature.getGeometry());

// create a buffer of 40 meters around each line
var buffered = jstsGeom.buffer(40);

// convert back from JSTS and replace the geometry on the feature
feature.setGeometry(parser.write(buffered));
```

Answer (score 3):

I also was interested in creating buffers around features but discovered the inaccuracies of the spherical mercator projection. Using JSTS it's possible to add buffers which are reasonably accurate (distance-wise) if you convert the first (or only) coordinate of the feature to a projection for your region. In my example I use North Carolina State Plane EPSG:32119. Then, I add the length of the buffer (in meters) to one dimension to form another point, the buffer length distance away. These two points form a line, the length of which is converted to a spherical mercator distance which is then used as the buffer distance in the JSTS code.

The routine is incorporated in my drag-and-drop code and applies to GeoJSON files only.

`ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);
var sp_projection = ol.proj.get('EPSG:32119');
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector();
var ddvector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    opacity: 1.0,
    visible: 0,
    source: vectorSource,
    style: styleFunction
});`

`var dragAndDropInteraction = new ol.interaction.DragAndDrop({
  formatConstructors: [ ol.format.GPX, ol.format.GeoJSON, ol.format.IGC, ol.format.KML, ol.format.TopoJSON ]
});`

`var map = new ol.Map({
    interactions: ol.interaction.defaults().extend([dragAndDropInteraction]),
    ...
});`

`dragAndDropInteraction.on('addfeatures', function(event) {
    ddvector.setVisible(true);
    vectorSource.addFeatures(event.features, event.projection);
    if(event.file.name.endsWith(".geojson") == true && document.getElementById('buff').value > '') {
        var bufferSource = new ol.source.Vector();
        var parser = new jsts.io.OL3Parser();
        for (var i = 0; i < event.features.length; i++) {
            var feature = event.features[i];
            var jstsGeom = parser.read(feature.getGeometry());
            if(feature.getGeometry().getType() == 'Point') { var pttype = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates(); } else { var pttype = feature.getGeometry().getFirstCoordinate(); }
            var point_sp = ol.proj.transform(pttype, 'EPSG:3857', sp_projection);
            var point_buff_sp = [point_sp[0], point_sp[1] + parseFloat(document.getElementById('buff').value)]; /* html element 'buff' holds length value */
            var buffy = ( new ol.geom.LineString([ ol.proj.transform([ point_sp[0], point_sp[1] ], sp_projection, 'EPSG:3857'), ol.proj.transform([ point_buff_sp[0], point_buff_sp[1] ], sp_projection, 'EPSG:3857') ], 'XY') ).getLength(); /* converts line 'buff' state plane meters long to a spherical mercator line and calculates length (buffy)*/
            var buffered = jstsGeom.buffer(buffy);
            feature.setGeometry(parser.write(buffered));
        }
    }
    map.getView().fit( vectorSource.getExtent(), (map.getSize()) );
});`